# Multiples key/values from app setting key on web.config

Tags: c#, web-config

I would like that with an unique key on web.config, retrieve a dictionary of keyvalues.

To explain myself i little better, i would like to generate a dictionary with as many entries as "key values separated by comma" in the value of MyCodes app setting.

```
<add key="MyCodes" value="Members,X4567423
                          NonMembers,Y32453
                          Registered,Z12312
                          ....
" />
```

As example and imaging that this is possible i would like to use it like

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyCodes"]["Members"]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you want to access it with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyCodes"]["Members"]` is a dream :)

What you can do is create a wrapper class that will parse `MyCodes` and split them for you. Then you can access the different values not trough your `ConfigurationManager` but trough your wrapper class.

Comment: its a pity but expected. I will do it this way, Thanks for the clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a [Settings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) and then create a Dictionary in it. Not only does it give you want you want, but you have better type safety as well.